# execute command from the terminal vs from a script - path with wildcard - prevent glob expansion

Tags: linux, shell, debian

I experience a strange problem and I think it have something to do with file/directory globbing

## script

```
echo "tar -zcvf $file $base/$target $exclude_args"
cd $base && tar -zcvf $file $base/$target $exclude_args
```

## output

```
tar -zcvf www_2017-04-24.tar.gz /var/www  --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/*' --exclude '/var/www/test'
```

When running the script the exclude path is omitted (every directory is gzipped)

When running the output directly from putty the directories under `/var/www/bak/*/*` is excluded from the gzip

## update

```
parse_exclude_paths (){
    # escape forward slashes to avoid the paths to expand
    args=$(echo "$exclude" | sed 's,/,\\\/,g')
    args=$(printf " --exclude '%s'" $args)
    # strip escapes
    echo "$args" | sed 's,\\\/,/,g'
}

exclude="/var/www/bak/*/* /var/www/test"
exclude_args=''
if [ ! -z "$exclude" ]; then
    exclude_args="$(parse_exclude_paths "$exclude")"
fi
```

## update 2

If the command is sent via SSH there is no problems and the exclude paths are excluded from the gzip

```
ssh root@$host 'cd '"$base"' && tar -zcvf $file '"$base/$target $exclude_args"
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? `bash` or other?

Comment: It just sh under debian..

Comment: Do you definitely wrap the exclude pattern in single quotes `'` both in the script and on the command line? Could it be that your terminal and/or text editor is translating single quotes to typographical quotes (or backquotes or something)?

Comment: yes... I have copy/pasted the output from the sh script directly and executed in putty

Comment: You are passing the literal argument `'/var/www/bak/*/*'` to tar, including the single quotes.  But `tar` does not want to see the single quotes, and when you invoke from the command line the shell is removing them for you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, its the same if I add the single quotes or not.. the exclude path is omitted from shell script anyway

Comment: No, it's very different.  If you omit the quotes completely, the glob is expanding and you are passing a whole slew of file names to `find`. You need to quote things in the right place.

Comment: The simplest solution (but neither safe nor robust) is to use `eval`

Comment: If you have a solution please create an answer :)

Comment: Have updated my question.. If the command is sent via SSH there is no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I snooped your question history and saw that you're familiar with PHP. Here's the equivalent problem in PHP:

```
function foo($arg1, $arg2) {
  echo "You passed $arg1 and $arg2\n";
}

$var='"one", "two"';
echo "Running: foo($var);\n";
foo($var);
```

> The echo prints `Running: foo("one", "two");` and that command works just fine if you copy-paste it!
>
> Why does `foo($var);` instead write `PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for foo()`?

The answer is of course that literal quotes in your variables don't matter for how the function is called. This is the same in both PHP and shell.

The solution in both PHP and Bash is to use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="www_2017-04-24.tar.gz"
base="/var"
target="www"
exclude_args=( --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/*' )

cd "$base" && tar -zcvf "$file" "$base/$target" "${exclude_args[@]}"
```

`sh` is more primitive and doesn't support arbitrary arrays, but we can reuse the positional parameters to the same effect:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="www_2017-04-24.tar.gz"
base="/var"
target="www"
set -- --exclude '/var/www/bak/*/*' # Now assigned to $1, $2, etc

cd "$base" && tar -zcvf "$file" "$base/$target" "$@"
```

Another option is to use `eval` to re-interpret a string as a shell command. This means that anyone who can influence your variables can take over your system, but that may be ok if all the variables come from users with equivalent privileges:

```
eval "tar -zcvf $file $base/$target $exclude_args"
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not that experienced in shell.. But there can be more than one `--exclude` path.. And the input with the exclude paths is a concatenated string like this `'/var/www/bak/*/* /var/test'`

Comment: have updated my question.. have come up with a solution to solve the problem with globbing when generating the string with the exclude paths.. all forward slashed is escaped and in the end striped

Comment: Have updated my question.. If the command is sent via SSH there is no problems

Comment: @clarkk Calling ssh is equivalent to `eval`.